# R recode within group ID

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to (1) create a unique group ID, and (2) recode one variable if it meets a condition within the group. I have the following data of ATM locations:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~address, ~date, ~terminal_id, ~location_type_description, 
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2017-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2018-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2019-11-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-01-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-12-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(date, as.Date)
  )
```

After 2018, the `location_type_description` variable was incorrectly coded as "Financial Institution".

Condition : if the `location_type_description` within an `address` and `terminal_id` is anything other than "Financial Institution" before the year 2019, then we recode the `location_type_description` to be whatever is was before 2019. But if the `location_type_description` is "Financial Institution" for all years (2017 onwards) then we know if was coded correctly. In our example, since it was "Gas Station" in 2017 and 2018, we know that anything after 2018 is actually a gas station. Here is what the output would look like in the toy data

```
data_clean <- tribble(
  ~address, ~date, ~terminal_id, ~location_type_description, ~group_identifier, ~location_corrected, ~location_changed,
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2017-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2018-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2019-11-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-01-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-02-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes"
  
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(date, as.Date)
  )
```

Comment: Is your "group_identifier" column a unique number for each ATM? IE would the next ATM on the list have group_identifier of 2?

Comment: Also, a quick but annoying note: you forgot the last i in "group_identifier" (spelled identifer) which might cause problems for anyone trying to work on your code. Sorry to be nitpicky! But I immediately got an error that group_identifier is not found when I tried to group by that column.

Comment: sorry I group_identifier is something that has to be created. I am defining this as its unique group because the address and terminal id is the same. An ATM in a different address with a different terminal ID would get its own group ID, and that would be 2. Sorry about the typo on identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few extra ATM locations to make sure it would work for various conditions.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~address, ~date, ~terminal_id, ~location_type_description, 
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2017-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2018-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2019-11-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-01-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-12-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "4 PRIVET DR LITTLE WHINGING", "2017-01-01", "AB123", "Gas Station",
  "4 PRIVET DR LITTLE WHINGING", "2018-01-01", "AB123", "Gas Station",
  "4 PRIVET DR LITTLE WHINGING", "2019-11-01", "AB123", "Gas Station",
  "4 PRIVET DR LITTLE WHINGING", "2020-01-01", "AB123", "Gas Station",
  "4 PRIVET DR LITTLE WHINGING", "2020-12-01", "AB123", "Gas Station",
  "42 WALLABY WAY SYDNEY AUSTRALIA", "2017-01-01", "XY10", "Other",
  "42 WALLABY WAY SYDNEY AUSTRALIA", "2018-01-01", "XY10", "Other",
  "42 WALLABY WAY SYDNEY AUSTRALIA", "2019-11-01", "XY10", "Financial Institution",
  "42 WALLABY WAY SYDNEY AUSTRALIA", "2020-01-01", "XY10", "Financial Institution",
  "42 WALLABY WAY SYDNEY AUSTRALIA", "2020-12-01", "XY10", "Financial Institution",
  "742 EVERGREEN TERRACE SPRINGFIELD", "2017-01-01", "4227", "Financial Institution",
  "742 EVERGREEN TERRACE SPRINGFIELD", "2018-01-01", "4227", "Financial Institution",
  "742 EVERGREEN TERRACE SPRINGFIELD", "2019-11-01", "4227", "Financial Institution",
  "742 EVERGREEN TERRACE SPRINGFIELD", "2020-01-01", "4227", "Financial Institution",
  "742 EVERGREEN TERRACE SPRINGFIELD", "2020-12-01", "4227", "Financial Institution",
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(date, as.Date)
  )

data_clean <- tribble(
  ~address, ~date, ~terminal_id, ~location_type_description, ~group_identifier, ~location_corrected, ~location_changed,
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2017-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2018-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2019-11-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-01-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-02-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution", 1, "Gas Station", "yes"
  
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(date, as.Date)
  )

# dataframe of address and group identifiers
groupID <- data.frame(terminal_id = unique(data$terminal_id), group_identifier = 1:length(unique(data$terminal_id)))
# dataframe of original location_types
OGloctype <- data %>%
  filter(date < as.Date('2019-01-01')) %>%
  rename(location_corrected = location_type_description) %>%
  select(c(terminal_id, location_corrected)) %>%
  distinct()

data %>%
  full_join(groupID, by = 'terminal_id') %>%
  full_join(OGloctype, by = 'terminal_id') %>%
  group_by(terminal_id) %>%
  # any() looks for any matches within the group
  mutate(location_changed = ifelse(any(location_corrected != location_type_description),
                                   'yes', 'no')) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I can use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
  library(dplyr)
  data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~address, ~date, ~terminal_id, ~location_type_description, 
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2017-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2018-01-01", "NC79", "Gas Station",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2019-11-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-01-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  "1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO", "2020-12-01", "NC79", "Financial Institution",
  
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(date, as.Date)
  )

data %>% 
  group_by(address) %>% 
  mutate(id = cur_group_id(), 
         location_type_description = location_type_description[1])
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   address [1]
#>   address               date       terminal_id location_type_description    id
#>   <chr>                 <date>     <chr>       <chr>                     <int>
#> 1 1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO 2017-01-01 NC79        Gas Station                   1
#> 2 1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO 2018-01-01 NC79        Gas Station                   1
#> 3 1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO 2019-11-01 NC79        Gas Station                   1
#> 4 1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO 2020-01-01 NC79        Gas Station                   1
#> 5 1 GATEWAY DR OROMOCTO 2020-12-01 NC79        Gas Station                   1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>